# Unable to start rails server due to access mysql server - access denied for 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have git cloned a repository in order to start contributing to a private project.

Now when I start the mysql server as well as the rails server I get the following error:

`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Mysql2::Error)`

Now I tried to login with the password that I found in the config/database.yml file but without success. What should I do to have the app run properly in my local environment?

Thanks for helping out.

the database.yml file:

```
  development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: sc_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: Mysql2047
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

 # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
 # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
 # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.

  test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: sc_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: Mysql2047
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: It will help if we can see your `database.yml` . I suppose you should create a new user on your machine, separately from `root` ,to connect to the db .

Comment: If you have not set a password for your root user for mysql then the password should be blank in your database.yml. Like @QumaraSixOneTour please post your database.yml

Comment: Are you able to connect to MySQL natively ( through the CLI or via WorkBench)? If you are able to then your issue is in your code (and supporting files) If not, then your issue is with your database.

Comment: I am able to login to mysql natively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was doing the trick for me:

First, instead of logging into mysql with

`mysql`

login like this:

`mysql -uroot`

root@localhost has all rights and NO password.

Next, I created the database and another user who I gave all rights.

`mysql> CREATE USER joe identified by 'foobar'`

`mysql> Grant All PRIVILEGES ON smartcheckups_development.* TO joe;`

Create the database:
`mysql> CREATE DATABASE sc_development;`

In my database.yml file, I updated the login & password with that of the above user joe. This will allow me to login.

Leave mysql via `\q`

Then

`bundle exec rake db:create`

and start rails `rails s`

Answer (score 0):

You need to start mysql server on your local machine, create database `sc_development` and  clear the password in your database settings file.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new MySQL user, with a username something other than `root`. It's a good practice to have a different database user for each different app.

You'll also, of course, need to grant privileges on the `sc_development` database to your app's user.

```
CREATE DATABASE sc_development;
CREATE USER sc IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON sc_development.* TO sc;
```

Something like that might do the trick.

Comment: Update: 

This did the trick.

Instead of logging into mysql with

``mysql```

login like this:

``mysql -uroot```